# Trvial spacing error, python?

Tags: python, binary

I feel embarrassed to even ask this, but python for some reason keep's giving me an error for my "l"

```
    def binary_search(l, targetValue):
          low = 0, high = len(array)
          while low <= high:
                mid = (high - low)/2
                if l[mid] == targetValue:
                     return "we found it!"
                elif l[mid] > targetValue:
                     low = mid - 1;
                else        l[mid] < targetValue: #this line seems to be the problem
                     high = mid + 1;
          print "search failure :( "
```

Comment: oh no it showed up wrong

Comment: Did you perhaps mix tabs and spaces in your file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although your spacing is abnormal, it actually isn't the problem here.

The problem is being caused by the fact that you are using `else` with an expression.  Instead, you need to use `elif`:

```
elif l[mid] < targetValue:
```

Or, even better, get rid of the expression altogether since you already tested for `l[mid] == targetValue` and `l[mid] > targetValue`:

```
else:
```

`else` means "for anything else, do this".  Thus, it does not evaluate nor support expressions.

Comment: Now it also says cannot assign it to literal, i thought assigning len(array) to high was acceptable no?

Comment: @user2928929 - No, you are going to want to do `low,  high = 0, len(array)`.

Comment: okay, it works! just curious, how exactly did that make a difference, didn't what I wrote previously say the same thing?

Comment: @user2928929 - No actually.  What you wrote before was being evaluated like this: `low = (0, high) = len(array)`.  In other words, `low` equals the tuple `(0, high)` which equals `len(array)`.  And, you can't assign a tuple (which is a literal) to a value (hence the error).  Mine however is being read like this `(low, high) = (0, len(array))`.  Though the two look very similar, mine is valid syntax.  Here is a reference: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Answer (score 2):

Your last line "#this line seems to be the problem" should be an ELIF or an ELSE with no statement afterwards.
For example, you do not need "ELSE {Condition}".  ELSE means "everything else."